# Groovy and Java Callbacks / Lambdas (Closures with a type)

Tags: groovy, lambda, closures

This is a callback I have in Java (`future` is a Mongo's [`SingleFutureResult`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/3.0.x/driver/src/main/org/mongodb/operation/SingleResultFuture.java)):

```
future.register(new SingleResultCallback<ArrayList<Document>>() {
    @Override
    void onResult(ArrayList<Document> documents, MongoException e) {
        //do something
    }
 })
```

With Java 8 I can use Lambdas to make it look like this:

```
future.register((documents, e) -> {
    //do something
});
```

Neat. However, I would like to call that Java method within a Groovy class. I know Groovy does currently not support jdk8 lambda's syntax, but the docs always stress that they have closures instead. If I try to use a closure in such a case it fails, as the closure is of type `Closure`, and not of type `SingleResultCallback`. Is there a way to have something like a closure with a different type? Is there any other way to make this work in a nice way? I know I can use the first solution, but that looks pretty weird within a groovy class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Groovy's closure syntax:

```
future.register( { documents, e -> 
    //do something
});
```

If there is ambiguity in a `register` method overload, it might need `as SingleResultCallback` after the closure declaration:

```
future.register { documents, e -> } as SingleResultCallback
```

---

This is an ambiguity scenario:

```
interface SingleResultCallback<T> {
    def onResult(T result)
}

interface Callback { def onResult(obj) }

class Future {
    void register(SingleResultCallback s) {
        println "registered: ${s.onResult(10)}"
    }

    void register (Callback r) {
        println "runnable=${r.onResult()}"
    }
}

new Future().register { it ** 2 }
```

Which fails with:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: 
    Ambiguous method overloading for method Future#register.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class Sam$_run_closure1] due 
    to overlapping prototypes between:
  [interface Callback]
  [interface SingleResultCallback]
```

And if `SingleResultCallback` had more than one method, a map coercion is a nice way to deal with it:

```
interface SingleResultCallback<T> {
    def onResult(T result)
    def onError
}

class Future {
    def register(SingleResultCallback s) {
        "registered: ${s.onResult(10)}"
    }

}

assert new Future().register( 
    [onResult: { it ** 2 } ] as SingleResultCallback ) == "registered: 100"
```

Comment: By "ambiguity", I think (s)he means "if the register method is overloaded"

Comment: The method register is not overloaded and should not be ambiguous. This is the source: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/3.0.x/driver/src/main/org/mongodb/MongoFuture.java. The first code snippet fails as of conflicting types `No signature of method: org.mongodb.operation.SingleResultFuture.register() is applicable for argument types: (com.mycompany.myproject.MyService$_handle_closure1)`. The second snipped is what I have been looking for, but couldn't find so far... Could you please point out more details about the ambiguity?

Comment: What version of groovy are you using? You need 2.3+ for Sam type coercion

Comment: Groovy version is 2.3.3

Comment: @Dónal, indeed, fixed.

Comment: @codeySmurf, i tried reproducing your error copying `SingleResultFuture` from Mongo's code, but no luck. It works correctly under 2.3.3 and fails with 2.1.9, as expected. https://gist.github.com/will-lp/c745c26b9177e5fd272a

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been a while since the question was made, and it's already replied, but i would also to add this example using Groovy Closure as callback (to see more go at https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html).

Groovy also support Closure as an Object, for instance:

```
Closure callback = { println 'Done!' } 
callback()
```

The output would be:

```
Done!
```

Above it's just another example:

```
def callbackList(){
      def list = ["RICE", "BEANS", "EGGS"]
      iterableList(list, { elem ->
        println elem
    })
}

def iterableList(list, callback){
   list.each {
     callback(it)
   }
}
```

The output would be:

```
RICE 
BEANS
EGGS
```